# mysql Set default value of a column as the current logged in user

Tags: mysql

How do you set the default value of a column to be the logged in user?

I am creating a "logging" table, and one of the columns should be the logged in user

```
(the output of "SELECT user();").
```

Is this possible?

**EDIT--What I tried:**

```
create trigger logtrigger_test before insert on logging_test for each row set new.changed_by=current_user();
```

**EDIT 2: describe table**

```
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id            | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| source_table  | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| foreign_id    | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                             | 
| field_changed | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             | 
| changed_by    | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             | 
| changed_on    | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

**EDIT 3: SAMPLE entries in table**

```
+----+---------------+------------+------------------+----------------------+---------------------+
| id | source_table  | foreign_id | field_changed    | changed_by           | changed_on          |
+----+---------------+------------+------------------+----------------------+---------------------+
| 0  | phone_numbers | 34         | home_phone       | jeff@localhost       | 2013-04-10 14:15:13 |
| 1  | contact_info  | 24         | first_name       | bob@localhost        | 2013-04-11 10:18:43 | 
| 2  | addresses     | 32         | home_address     | autoscript@localhost | 2013-04-12 11:10:37 |
| 3  | addresses     | 36         | business_address | bob@localhost        | 2013-04-12 14:56:17 |
| 4  | addresses     | 36         | business_address | jeff@localhost       | 2013-04-12 15:25:52 |
+----+---------------+------------+------------------+----------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: So it is not possible then?

Comment: That's my read on it.  OTOH, most ppl don't bother with that, as they usually connect to the db through some application and application context.  In that case, it's usually more practical for the application to send the user information.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is create a table that knows when any other table is changed (using triggers). I guess I could have the application that would be updating my table send a username variable.

Comment: Well if you're using triggers then you can `update` a column with a `CURRENT_USER`, but that's not a default value.

Comment: That is what I am trying now, but it broke my table. I added it to the question above.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL Syntax;

Comment: please post your table definition.

Comment: @Jeff That's all ? There's gotta be more.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, this is generally not the way one creates audit tables.  Typically, when you want to log inserts, deletes, and updates, you would do something like this:

Create a table like foo:

```
create table foo (
    foo_id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    foo_data varchar(100) not null
    );
```

Then you usually make an audit table like so:

```
create table foo_audit (
    foo_audit_id not null auto_increment primary key,
    foo_id int,
    foo_data varchar(100),
    change_type char(1),
    change_timestamp timestamp default current_timestamp,
    change_login varchar(100)
    );
```

Then you make a trigger or triggers on the table like so:

```
create trigger trg_foo_insert
    after insert on foo
    for each row 
    insert into foo_audit (
        foo_id,
        foo_data,
        change_type,
        change_login
        )
    values (
        new.foo_id,
        new.foo_data,
        'I',
        current_user
        );
```

You would make a "U" trigger for updates, and a "D" trigger for deletes.

I think the main problem you are having is you are trying to do a "one size fits all" audit table; I think this pattern will cause you a lot of issues, you don't necessarily have the data you're looking for, and you will still need to write at least one trigger for each table you are auditing.

The actual answer to your question, however, is that you were either setting a trigger on a table that was not being inserted to, or trying to update a column on a table where the column did not exist.

Comment: Thanks! You've answered the question I asked and the one I didn't!

Comment: @Jeff if you are satisfied with the answer, be sure to mark it as such.  Thanks, and good luck!

Comment: autoincrement should be auto_increment

Comment: Whups!  There, it's fixed.

Comment: Note that [current_user](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) isn't always the currently logged in user. I find `session_user()` is what I'm looking for in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

We can add a column name in any table having default constraint as system User.
Here I'm going to add ModifiedBy Column in a table.

```
ALTER TABLE [AccessDB].[dbo].[MediaTable]
ADD ModifiedBY varchar(100) default  SUSER_SNAME()
```

Comment: Is SUSER_SNAME() valid in MySQL?