# MySQL - 'Updated By' column to automatically update with user who modified the row?

Tags: mysql, database

Here's my table.

```
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID                | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Postcode          | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Town              | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Region            | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Company Name      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Fee               | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Company Benefits  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Date Updated      | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Website           | mediumtext   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Updated By        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Notes             | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| LNG               | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| LAT               | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

You can see we have an "Updated by" column.

How can I make it so that, when a user updates the row, the "Updated By" column automatically updates (or inserts if it's a new row they're adding) with the currently logged-in users name?

Many Thanks

Comment: if you using session then first fetch session then update the table with that session

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: Do you mean by `logged-in` users, the `database` user? or the users from the application layer ?

Comment: Wajeeh, I mean logged-in users, whenever a user is logged in, their name shall appear in 'updated by' my users access the database through MS Access (I know, I hate it too. But they demand it.) but I also have a webapp they use and can edit data, and so may be more suitable to have MySQL run a trigger of some sort every time an entry is modified / updated

Answer (score 0):

You will have to explicitly make sure about that and whenever an `UPDATE` is happening then you need to update that column as well saying below. Best way to assure it, have your application logic fill in the column whenever an `UPDATE` to the record is happening from current logged-in user principle or claim

```
update tbl1
set ...,
 Updated By = <logged in user name>
where Id = <some val>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use USER() or CURRENT_USER() in Update or Insert statements to achieve needed effect. 
From my side - the only one secure way is to create stored procedures, providing inserts or updates to desired table.
Indeed, this problem was discussed here:
[mysql Set default value of a column as the current logged in user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978334/mysql-set-default-value-of-a-column-as-the-current-logged-in-user)

Comment: Thank you, however I'd already seen this, the answer given here is a few years back, and rather complex for a seemingly simple task, as well as using 2 different tables. So I wonder if there's a far more simplistic way that can all be done within the same table on row updates?

Comment: The exact answer is - no way. However, if you create stored procedure that updates the table - it will bring needed result.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this !

```
CREATE TRIGGER `updater`.`tableName_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `tableName`
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
     Set New.Updated_By = current_user();
END
```