# MySql CREATE TABLE and a varchar column with default value of db-function "USER"

Tags: mysql

With MySql.

There is a way to set a default value.
I know how to do a hard-coded string.

I'm trying to use a

of

USER()

CURRENT_USER

CURRENT_USER()

See 'inserted_by' column below.

If I remove

DEFAULT USER()

it works ok.  But that is not what I need.

I've tried all 3 above (after the word DEFAULT).  I cannot figure out the magic syntax sugar.

```
CREATE TABLE `department` (
    `department_key` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name_of` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
    `inserted_by` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT USER(),
    `create_date_off_set` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
    CONSTRAINT `PK_department` PRIMARY KEY (`department_key`)
    )
    ;
```

References:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/built-in-function-reference.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

"My" Version:

```
SELECT VERSION();

8.0.23
```

Comment: Why not creating a [trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978334/mysql-set-default-value-of-a-column-as-the-current-logged-in-user) ?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: using a trigger........is metaphorically like "reaching between your legs to scratch your back".. yeah it works... but c'mon.

Comment: Discussion about this found here : https://blog.koehntopp.info/2020/09/07/mysql-generated-columns-and-virtual-indexes.html#allowed-and-disallowed-functions

Comment: @granadaCoder it seems that in the end you are *reaching between your legs to scratch your back* (lol)  ... and it happens a lot when using MySQL

Comment: :)   My "c'mon" is directed at MySql.     I am adding this new "find" to my self-notes about "So you think you know MySql??"      Thanks for input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The default value specified in a DEFAULT clause can be a literal constant or an expression. With one exception, ***enclose expression default values within parentheses to distinguish them from literal constant default values.***

So you want `inserted_by varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT (CURRENT_USER())`

Unfortunately, MySQL does not allow this.

> `Default value expression of column 'inserted_by' contains a disallowed function: current_user.`

I can't find any reason why it would be disallowed in the documentation, but that's MySQL for you.

Instead, use an insert trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_app_users
  BEFORE INSERT ON department 
  FOR EACH ROW
  SET new.inserted_by = COALESCE(new.inserted_by, current_user())
```

Comment: CURRENT_USER() is disallowed because it's nondeterministic. If you use statement based replication and INSERT a row, the value of CURRENT_USER() isn't necessarily the same on the replica. This affects several MySQL statements, and some solve it by expanding the value before writing to the binary log. But INSERT doesn't do that. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-features-current-user.html

Comment: @BillKarwin I'm not sure why being non-deterministic matters, but that's MySQL. "*A function is deterministic if, given the same data in tables, multiple invocations produce the same result, independently of the connected user.*" Wait, how is `current_timestamp` allowed?

Comment: "But that's MySql for you".  Boo.  It works in Postgres, Ms-Sql-Server (CURRENT_USER) (no parentheses) and ORACLE (USER) (no parentheses).  Thanks for the response.  I am getting the "disallowed" error now.

Comment: Current timestamp and other time-based functions are allowed because binary log events set the timestamp according to the current time when the event was created on the source instance. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-replication-excerpt/8.0/en/replication-features-functions.html If you dump the binary log with `mysqlbinlog`, you'll see the timestamp being set in each event before the logged SQL statement.

Comment: @BillKarwin I don't see how that makes `current_timestamp` deterministic, multiple invocations won't produce the same result given the same data, but hey... that's MySQL for you. They set the time for replication, but not the user? Is there a reason?

Comment: Well, when you're in charge of that product, you can set the priorities.